# Always visible tinymce toolbar

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, toolbar, visible

I am working on a cms for a smaller company and they want inline editing, my only problem is that they want to have the tinymce toolbar visible at all times, disabled when not in use and active when focus on a field.

So my question is: How can i have a tinymce toolbar that is constantly visible, and disabled when not in use and active when it is?

Comment: Tried to work with the ui.Toolbar and a lot of other fixes, but I have finally found a solution, not the best, but It works, just needed to get a new perspective.